# How to write the " <a href='javascript: function" and pass parameter at .ashx

Tags: javascript, jquery, ashx

I want to write the table edit and delete event with call javascript function at .ashx.
and use the jasn pass the table html to .aspx.
but I don't know how to pass a parameter to javascript function at .ashx

```
<td rowspan='2'><a href='#' class='toggle'><img title='Details' src='/images/Detail24.png'/></a>&nbsp;<a href='javascript:EditRow('' + i_dtData.Rows[nRow][1].ToString() + ''); return false;' class='toggle'><img title='Edit' src='/images/Edit24.png'/></a>&nbsp;<a href='javascript:DeleteRow('" + i_dtData.Rows[nRow][1].ToString() + "'); return false;' class='toggle'><img title='Delete' src='/images/Delete24.png'/></a>"
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK5cA.png

Comment: You're obviously trying to make a call to an ASP.NET HTTP Handler. So, what control is this hyperlink being generated in? A GridView? A COTS control? Those kind of details are essential to getting an answer.

Comment: Have you tried <a href='#' onclick='javascript:EditRow('' + i_dtData.Rows[nRow][1].ToString() + '');'>?